# Worklight 6.1 latest ifix pack gives popup in BB10 while accessing geolocation services

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I am working on developing an application for BB10 using geolocation services. Initially the application was on worklight 6.0 and had following permission set in config.xml:

read_geolocation

After upgrading to worklight 6.1, while accessing geolocation services, I am getting following popup:

local:// wants to access your location. Allow?

This popup was not coming in earlier version.

Also, after migrating to latest ifix pack, I added the folloing permission as well:

access_location_services

Still the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

AAV,

This was found to be a defect in Cordova.
If you'd like to receive a fix, please [open a PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) so a fix for Worklight 6.1 which you are using, could be supplied to you. Provide a link to this question.